# Remove URLs from journal articles but not web pages in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, urls

I'm using BibTeX (requirement of the journal I'm submitting to), and I'm referencing mostly journal articles, but also one blog post. I would like to hid the urls in the references list, but *only* for the journal articles. The url should still display for the blog post. Is this possible without removing the URLs from the `.bib` file?

Comment: Presumably you have to use a fixed BibTeX style (`.bst` file)? The usual way to handle things is to select printing of fields in the `.bst` file, but that's not possible if you have to use one and can't edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an hack if there is only one blog, and key for the blog is known.

This solution also assumes:

1) that the `url` `bibtex` field is rendered by `\url{<field>}`.

2) `natbib` or other bibliography managers modifying (and adding arguments) to \bibitem` are not used (though, in some cases this is easy to fix).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bbl}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{abc}
Author.
\newblock Title.
\newblock {\em Journal}, 2013. \url{http://article.example.com}

\bibitem{cde}
blogAuthot.
\newblock blogtitle. \url{blog.examnple.com}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{filecontents}

\let\oldurl\url
\providetoggle{blog}
\renewcommand{\url}[1]{\iftoggle{blog}{\oldurl{#1}}{}}

\xapptocmd{\@bibitem}{
  \ifstrequal{#1}{cde}
    {\toggletrue{blog}}
    {\togglefalse{blog}}}
    {}
    {}
\begin{document}

This is a reference to an article \cite{abc}, this a reference to a blog \cite{cde}.

%\bibliographystyle{<style creating bbl with \url>}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to have a toggle for the blog, and based on this `\url` is define to essentially gobble its content. The toggle is set to true based on the content of the bibtex `key` for the blog (`cde` in the example above). It is possible to extend to above to a list of values.

Comment: I'd prefer `\renewcommand{\url}{\iftoggle{blog}{\oldurl}{\@gobble}` (requires the usual `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`) so the argument to `\url` is not untimely read and tokenized.